# What is the song playing in Code Geass Episode 14: Geass vs Geass

Tags: music, code-geass

I have recently started watching Code Geass, and I find the soundtrack absolutely amazing! There is one song in particular that I would like to find the name of.

It starts playing at about 20:14 in the episode "Geass vs Geass" where [Lelouch goes to hug Shirley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=091vibikAOE). I think it may be called "Lelouch of the Rebellion", but I am not sure.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the youtube link and a small description of the scene.

Answer (score 3):

The song is [*Masquerade*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLvfKm_eYfo&t=27m49s), which is Track 13 on the first OST according to the metadata on my iPhone/iPod.

> **Masquerade**
>   *Vocals: Hitomi
>
>   Lyrics: Kuroishi Hitomi
>
>   Composition: Kuroishi Hitomi*

While I can't time the song perfectly to where I believe [it starts in the episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fTprZ-2sBc&t=20m14s), one point that makes me believe they are the same song is at [0:51](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLvfKm_eYfo&t=28m41s) of the song which matches the song at [20:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fTprZ-2sBc&t=20m54s) of the episode (in the link)

Comment: @Mightycat it was just a matter of finding the exact scene and going though all the OSTs. just took me a while to confirm it was the song because while they had the same background beat i couldn't find a point where i could prove they have the same lyrics. if this is the correct answer don't forget to accept it

Comment: @Memor-X it is the correct answer.

Comment: ehm, how do i accept it? :P

Comment: @Mightycat there should be a tick button on the left, under the down arrow (down vote)

Answer (score 0):

The only place I could find it is [here](https://www.bilibili.com/video/av384332/). Could find it neither on iTunes nor youtube. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯